# Measuring current draw from servo

Tags: current-measurement, servo

I am trying to measure the current draw of a digital hobby servo (futaba 3050) to estimate its applied torque.

To implement this I am using a shunt resistor setup with an IC that will send a proportional current through its output (P3) which will then be drawn through a  resistor (R2) giving a output voltage that will be measurable by the MCU.

(The setup is shown in the schematic below, using a 0.2ohm shunt resistor and the IC ZXCT1009FTA by 'Diodes Incorporated')

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8ajrN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

After having implemented this on a PCB I have been testing the circuit and I have a few questions regarding my results.

When first testing the circuit I used a simple power resistor to draw a fixed current through the wire called "Servo Supply" in the schematic. And while varying the current from my lab bench power supply through the power resistor the voltage on "ADC measurement" changed proportionally to the current as expected.

After passing this simple first test I then moved on to the real test, actually running a servo as load. But unfortunately I ran into trouble. I probed the voltage at "ADC measurement" pin. And the result from running the Servo (keeping it at a fixed position but applying small torque) can be seen in the first image.

[image: Servo current measurement low torque]

When then applying more torque the measured voltage is kept at the same level but kept high for a longer time. Actually making the current measurement behave like a PWM. Here is another image with more torque applied to the servo.

[image: Servo current measurement more torque]

After searching for more information about doing current measurements on servos I read about this behaviour which I assume is originating from that the servo is controlled with a PWM signal?

So to summarize into the actual question:
How will I go about to measure the current (torque) of the servo in a good way? I read about measuring the average current draw for example by adding a capacitor (at the ADC pin I assume), but I feel unsure about how I would choose said capacitor?

Or could I just do ADC measurements and take the average over a full PWM period?

Thankful for any input/help. If there's any additional info needed I am happy to extend the question.

Best regards, Mattias

Comment: What is the pulse rep rate min? I'm thinking of a high order Nyquist LPF such as those used for Telephony.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Hello Tony, I am sorry but I do not know what you mean with pulse rep rate min?

Comment: what is the pulse to pulse interval time (max.) or rate (min.)?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 It is 20 ms between the pulses (which would be the same as the period of the PWM signal used to the servo).

Comment: Chances are the motor pulses are triggered in direct response to the input PWM command based on the position error measured relative to what that is commanding, so would match its rate - nominally 50 Hz by tradition, but it would depend on the source in use.  A more sophisticated servo with a digital implementation of the onboard PID loop might run the loop at an internally determined frequency and use the PWM input only to update the setpoint.  In any case the output is likely to be PWM, as linear motor drive wastes power, and these are designed to run on batteries.

Comment: Can you average in software or prefer to use nth order LPF  Nyquist filter and sample with ADC at some rate?  Another approach is I to V to VCO to counter average in software and reset before overflow. or just measure I in software at a fast rate and crunch the results like a LiPo Coulomb counter

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 The idea I had closest to mind was averaging in software (running a stm32f042 processor as core),  as I am not sure how to make the filter properly. Would it simply be a low pass filter with a cutoff at 50Hz or something? However I am open to both solutions, and wanted to ask here as I would assume it have been done before and I'd like the best solution possible (and learn about it aswell). Is it correct to assume that the average of the ADC measurements would be the average amperage drawn and hence proportional to the torque?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes, this is what I assumed (and the voltage pulses measured and shown in the pictures are at 50Hz). However, I am not fully sure on the full details on digital servos compared to analog servos.

Comment: @MattiasWallin not a simple filter. In order to suppress fundamental f ,  since narrowest pulse determines >>2x min.sampling rate , filter must suppress ripple by 20dB for 10% err. or 40dB for 1% error and compute order of filter from fastest result desired below 25Hz with 6dB per octave per order

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I am afraid there is some knowledge gaps here. I have previously mainly simulated filters earlier, for example making a bandpass which would eliminate high frequency noise and make sure the gain of a system is as specified within a certain frequency range. However I have less experience using them in my circuits. What I was thinking when I read "add a cap to average the voltage" was simply that you would add a capacitor that would be charged with the "pulsed" signal and in that way smooth out the voltage over the period giving you somewhat of an average?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 That's what I am currently not understanding. When I have previously been using filters, I have been filtering away undesired signals. But (in my head) I don't want to filter away the signal, but rather "read it" over a longer time frame? I think I understand what I want to accomplish conceptually/with hardware, but I can't translate it into the theory with filters. If I want to understand you better what should I read up on? I know some of nyquist shannon theorem and such, but I don't know what you are referring to when you say "suppress ripple by 20dB for 10% err" etc

Comment: All pulses have a DC content and fundamental Ac and many harmonics. All fundamental AC & harmonics must be rejected to preserve DC average. You decide if you want average over 1 second or 1/10th or 1/20th second etc implies how steep the filter must be to reject AC ripple which causes sampling error. These can be weighted moving averages in software for successive where Sum of weights =1 and sample interval following some algorithm of ratio of sampling rate to pulse rate and longer filters require more memory and complex coefficients or use textbook filter designs cascaded.

Comment: If you are interested in cumulative Ah battery drain with accuracy ,that can be done too.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Okay, so say I want to suppress all fundamental AC and harmonics. Is the fundamental frequency of my signal (the signal measured in the pictures) then 50Hz? And how do I make a hardware filter to supress this?

If I have that 50Hz voltage signal and I want to find its average over it's own full period. e.g. find the average current each 20 ms?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 And thank you very much for taking your time, I might probably go with finding the average with software as it will be easiest for me I think, but I am keen to learn more about the electronics/hardware.

Answer (score 1):

- just for giggles on a spreadsheet
- a simple software filter but ADC samples synchronously to 10x servo rate. (500Hz)  in order to demonstrate limitations of simple low pass filters on delay and ripple.
- Rolling averages were done for different # of samples 1,3,5,7,7W (centre weighted) , 11, 19, 39  *for less than 80 samples of servo pulses*
- asynchronous sampling would have aliasing errors.
- Note simple rolling average adds group delay or latency to the peak current.  But an optimal "Nyquist" filter would not. (as much)
  [image]